# CSS animation not working in IE11 and Edge

Tags: css, css-animations, internet-explorer-11, compatibility, microsoft-edge

I have tried putting my keyframes at the top of my CSS, not in the media query, http-equiv set to IE=Edge, etc.

It's a fairly basic .png image used during website load with simple rotate/y animation shown in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/N4Design/d4v0uw36/15/) code below.

```css
.loader-background {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 99999999;
    background-color: #eef0eb;
}
.loader {
    position: absolute;
    height: 50px;
    width: auto;
    top: calc(50% - 25px);
    left: calc(50% - 25px);
    -webkit-animation-name: loader-animate;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-name: loader-animate;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes loader-animate {
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(360deg);
        transform: rotatey(360deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatex(360deg);
        transform: rotatex(360deg);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(0deg);
        transform: rotatey(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatex(0deg);
        transform: rotatex(0deg);
    }
}
@keyframes loader-animate {
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(360deg);
        transform: rotatey(360deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatex(360deg);
        transform: rotatex(360deg);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatey(0deg);
        transform: rotatey(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotatex(0deg);
        transform: rotatex(0deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="loader-background">
  <img src="https://s30.postimg.org/7dct7bspd/GTG_FB_Logo.png" class="loader"/>
</div>
```

Works perfectly in Chrome and FF but not in Edge and IE11.

Comment: This animation doesn't do anything in Firefox, either.

Comment: @TylerH: it does "work" in FF but not perfectly - thanks for the correction. I have updated the image link to shared hosting so you can see it, which is why it wasn't working at all.  The image rotates on the y-axis/vertically, but not the x-axis/horizontally

Comment: OK, so I figured it myself.  You need to set the x **and** y rotation in every stage definition of the keyframe.  Chrome obviously does better at filling in the blanks... [revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/N4Design/d4v0uw36/17/).

Answer (score 0):

simply use rotate(..)
Animation will be a little different, but it will work

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I figured it myself. You need to set the x and y rotation in every stage definition of the keyframe. Chrome obviously does better at filling in the blanks... [revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/N4Design/d4v0uw36/17/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes loader-animate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(0deg);
    transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(360deg);
    transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(360deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(360deg) rotatey(360deg);
    transform: rotatex(360deg) rotatey(360deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(360deg) rotatey(0deg);
    transform: rotatex(360deg) rotatey(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(0deg);
    transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes loader-animate {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(0deg);
    transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(360deg);
    transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(360deg);
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(360deg) rotatey(360deg);
    transform: rotatex(360deg) rotatey(360deg);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(360deg) rotatey(0deg);
    transform: rotatex(360deg) rotatey(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(0deg);
    transform: rotatex(0deg) rotatey(0deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: So, next problem was that doesn't work fully on mobile but that was just a matter of adding `-webkit-perspective: 500px;` to the .loader-background